# StackOverflowException in Serilog Enricher

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, stack-overflow, serilog

I'm writing an enricher for Serilog and I want to add a property that may trigger a new log event, in practice:

```
public void Enrich(LogEvent logEvent, ILogEventPropertyFactory propertyFactory)
{
    ISession session = /* HttpContext.Session */;
    logEvent.AddPropertyIfAbsent(propertyFactory.CreateProperty("ValueFromSession", session.GetString("ValueFromSession")));
    /* other properties ... */
}
```

I want to be able to add a value from my http session to my logs, so I use `LogContext.PushProperties` with a custom enricher. ASP.NET Core logs a warning whenever an expired session is read, which triggers my enricher, but whenever I attempt to read from the session in the enricher it warns me about the expired session, which triggers a new instance of my enricher (ad infitum). This causes a `StackOverflowException` which does not seem to be catchable with a `try` block.

Is there any way to disable logging when in an `Enrich` method? Or can I detect this kind of recursion somehow (other than parsing a stacktrace)?

Comment: check carefully is there any circular reference

Comment: There is an indirect reference between between my code and ASP.NET's as described in the question, but I can't remove the reference because I need to be able to read from the session and I want ASP.NET to warn me about expired sessions.

Comment: Exceptions thrown from within `Enrich()` should be caught by Serilog and not result in another top-level exception handler being triggered. It sounds like something else might be going on here; can you possibly add a stack trace to the question? Cheers!

Comment: The issue isn't that it's logging a thrown exception, ASP.NET is just logging a warning whenever I access `HttpContext.Session` in this particular case, which I want to be able to do in my enricher. The end result of this mutual recursion is a stack overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem with my custom `ILogger` implementation (not using Serilog). It happens anytime the Session object is accessed. I managed to fix this by adding DataProtection with persisted keys to my application on startup.

```
services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo("keys"));
```

I haven't gone too deeply into the implementation details, but from what I see in the [DistributedSession](https://github.com/aspnet/Session/blob/be6b099f6ce45bc1308f2135dbd1bfe295e20a98/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session/DistributedSession.cs) code, the "Accessing expired session" message is logged when an old session key is detected. The problem here is that the logging happens before the `isAvailable` flag is set to `true` which causes the recursion. I don't know why adding DataProtection avoids this issue, but it could that the DataProtection causes the `_isNewSessionKey` to be always `true`.

Another workaround suggested in [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2935#issuecomment-371395553) would be to add a middleware to save the Session items you want to log to HttpContext.Items. Then retrieve those items in your logger.